# "the `and_then` method cannot be invoked on a trait object" error when type annotations are added to the `and_then`

Tags: rust

I have a function passed to `and_then` that returns a type not known to the compiler. When chained with other option methods, type annotations are required.

```
fn main() {
    let w = Some("hi".to_string());
    let x: Option<&String> = w.as_ref();

    //fails:
    let y: Option<String> =
        x.and_then::<String, FnOnce(Option<&String>) -> Option<String>>(|_inner: &String| None);

    //ok:
    let y: Option<String> = x.and_then(|_inner: &String| None);
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=77fdec86ccf6587d0ac83220db8e7c44)

Adding the mandatory annotations causes this compiler error:

```
error: the `and_then` method cannot be invoked on a trait object
 --> src/main.rs:7:11
  |
7 |         x.and_then::<String, FnOnce(Option<&String>) -> Option<String>>(|_inner: &String| None);
  |           ^^^^^^^^
```

I assume it is complaining about the `FnOnce` trait, but I don't see what this has to do with `x`.

I would like to understand what is going wrong here.

Ultimately, the goal is to have this `and_then` in a chained statement, which is why the annotations are needed.

```
let y = x
    .and_then::<String, FnOnce(Option<&String>) -> Option<String>>(|_inner: &String| None)
    .and(Some("new String".to_string()));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple problems here:

- Closures are an [anonymous type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45935100/how-do-rust-closures-work-and-how-does-it-execute-a-closure), which means that you *cannot name them*.
- It's currently impossible to have a bare trait like `FnOnce` because [it is unsized](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28044231/155423).
- `|| foo` isn't a trait, it's a concrete type.

Instead, [specify the return type of the closure](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41394751/155423):

```
let y = x
    .and_then(|_inner| -> Option<String> { None })
    .and(Some("new String".to_string()));
```

Or [qualify the type of the `None`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37886379/155423):

```
let y = x
    .and_then(|_inner| None::<String>)
    .and(Some("new String".to_string()));
```

Or avoid the chaining:

```
let y: Option<String> = x.and_then(|_inner| None);
let y = y.and(Some("new String".to_string()));
```